# Toggling from Find & Replace to just Find in Cloud9 IDE

Tags: cloud9-ide

How to go from `Find & Replace` to just `Find`. My keyword mode is Sublime. In Sublime if you `Cmd + F`, you toggle Find and if you `Alt + Cmd + F` you toggle `Find & Replace`. This is not working for me, it won't let me get out of F & R. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Find & replace` and  `Find` dialogs are combined in Cloud9.
Textbox for replace is always shown but it is small, when empty and not focused.
In Cloud9 `Cmd-F` focuses find textbox and `Cmd-Alt-F` focuses replace textbox, but they both open the same dialog.